# Not able to achieve end to end encryption in openshift 4.3 route

Tags: encryption, openshift

We have a AngularJS application where we have a nodejs app which creates certificates and key for service hostname only when HTTPS port is 443. Then created certificates are consumed in nginx as shown below:

```
<% if ENV["HTTPS__ENABLED"] == "true" %>
listen <%= ENV["HTTPS__PORT"] %> ssl;
# These files are generated by the node app
ssl_certificate /cert.csr;
ssl_certificate_key /tls_private_key.csr;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
<% end %>
```

But when I set 443 port in route with re-encrypt termination it gives below error while accessing application

```
Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
```

The request is not even reaching pod. If I create route with edge termination is gives error

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

As in Edge termination there is no encryption from router to pod.
I cannot use passthrough termination policy as we have path in our route which is not supported by passthrough termination.

can someone please let me know how to achieve end to end encryption in openshift 4.3. We do not use custom domain here.

I was checking the way for creating re-encrypt route 
`oc create route reencrypt --service=frontend --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --dest-ca-cert=destca.crt --ca-cert=ca.crt --hostname=www.example.com`

but as we are not using custom domain our route should use default cert and key right? So no need to provide those right? I am not getting how to create --dest-ca-cert for this route.

Comment: Reencrypt is the right way to go in your case then. Can you add the output for `oc get route <name-of-route> -o yaml` for your reencrypt Route that gives you the "Application is not available" error? Also, you should be able to run `oc create route reencrypt --service=frontend --dest-ca-cert=destca.crt` to create this route, where "destca.crt" is the certificate for the CA used for your certificate in your NGINX "/cert.csr", does that work? If not, what is the error message?

Comment: this is yaml of route----->host: mts-test.mts-trep-78cduhduc7388d9333-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
  path: /ptd-ui/
  port:
    targetPort: ptd-ui-https
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
    termination: reencrypt
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ptd-ui-test-service

Comment: @simon how to create destca.crt or it should be same cert.csr used in nginx?

Comment: `destca.crt` should contain the root CA certificate that is also the same root as in your `cert.csr`. So use `openssl` to extract the root certificate from your certificate chain.

Comment: @simon cert.csr has only one cert in it not a chain. And these cert and key are getting created inside a pod. So in order to create destca should I copy to my local machine from pod? and then extract root Cert? Can you provide a way to get root cert from such csr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS is already enabled in our AngularJS app using a nodejs app which creates cert and key which is consumed by Nginx.Pod inside the cluster uses TLS, it’s issued by a CA, that’s the cert we should put in destinationCACert for the route.The CA cert is how the router determines if it can trust the upstream POD for the TLS communication.

We used ca.cert located at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` as destination certificate while creating re-encrypt route. We selected HTTPS port while creating route.
`oc create route reencrypt --service=frontend --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --dest-ca-cert=destca.crt --ca-cert=ca.crt --hostname=www.example.com`

Here tls.cert and tls.key is not needed for us as we were using default domain of the openshift cluster.Only cert we used is `--dest-ca-cert` which is also found at secret `service-serving-cert-signer-sa-token-l42lm` of `openshift-service-ca` namespace

Answer (score 0):

For re-encrypt route the pod needs to be configured with a TLS certificate as it has to respond to TLS request originated at Openshift router. You already have it as evident from the error you are getting when trying to use edge route.

Now this TLS certificate, must be created with same host name that you want to use in the actual route. It is not necessary that this TLS certificate is a CA signed one, but the hostname must match with the route. Only then the route can forward traffic to  your pod.

Comment: so I have host  `mts-test.mts-trep-78cduhduc7388d9333-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud` in my route. So I should create re-encrypt route with destination certificate which is for my hostname mts-test.mts-trep-78cduhduc7388d9333-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud?

Comment: Yes, you may face issues with longer than 64 char hostnames. This may be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234324/openssl-self-signed-certificate-with-a-common-name-longer-than-64-bytes

Comment: Cant I use the default certificate one from openshift? As I am not using custom domain.Destination cert specifies a CA certificate to validate the endpoint certificate right?

Comment: To configure your angular js app to listen on a secure port, you will need to configure both the crt and key.

Comment: In my nginx app I have both key and cert. But while creating a  re-encrypt  route `oc create route reencrypt --service=frontend --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --dest-ca-cert=destca.crt --ca-cert=ca.crt --hostname=www.example.com` there is no need to mention --cert and --key right? as I am not using custom domain. I just need to provide destination cert which specifies a CA certificate to validate the endpoint certificate right? My question is how to create such destination cert? Is there any document for it?

Comment: So you have  nginx pod in front of angularJS ? In that case, the TLS that you configured in nginx should have the same route hostname as CN. Please note that, here the communication from nginx to angular is still unencrypted

Comment: I have a angularJa app and I used nginx as well. Inside app I have a nodejs app which creates a cert and key using POD hostname as commonName and service hostname as subjectAltName. I am using forge to create these cert and key. Once those are created my nginx container consumes it. So Should I create a destination certificate for service hostname? if yes how to create it?